# Write code using a textbox

Tags: vb.net

So I am using a listbox which has a list of game names on it, when you select a game from the list and click the button it starts the game from the exe. This works well and good, but I want to make it easier for me to add new games without having to edit the code all of the time. I have 2 text boxes; txtDataAdd and txtFilePath. txtDataAdd adds a name to the listbox, and txtFilePath is for the user to input the file path of the game and then the box adds it to the code, however I have no idea how to do it, or if it's even possible, here's a snippet of code:

```
    Dim sDataAdd As String = txtDataAdd.Text
    Dim sCodeAdd As String = txtFilePath.Text
    Dim sFinalAdd As String
    Dim test As String = "Documents\New Text Document.txt"

    lbListBox.Items.Add(sDataAdd)

    sFinalAdd = "If lbListBox.SelectedItem = "" & sDataAdd & "" then
                     sData1 = "" & sCodeAdd & "" "


End Sub
```

sFinalAdd is the code I want to be written when the button is clicked, and is it also possible to save the new code so that it doesn't reset every time the application is restarted? Thanks.

Comment: Btw for people downvoting, can you explain what for and maybe help me.

Comment: because it's tagged with the wrong language ?

Comment: Hmm really? I'm using visual basic with visual studio 2015...

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are not the same languages

Comment: ahh I didn't know that, ill correct it.

Comment: VB.Net (used in Visual Studio) is not VBA (used in MS Office products). They're not the same language. It's much easier to program if you actually know which language you're using to do so. It also makes searching for things related to your code work better.

Comment: I have been doing this for 5 weeks or so and I'm not so experienced. I just assumed VBA stood for Visual Basic, my mistake.

Comment: It partly does, VBA = Visual Basic Application (for Excel, Word, ...) and VB = Visual Basic

Comment: The VS tag doesnt even apply.  You arent asking anything related to VS (how to modify a menu, change a short cut key etc).  The tags have words on them describing their usage

Comment: VBA is *Visual Basic for Applications*, and it is not capable of being used from Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe try writing the data into a file and then let your program read from that file each time (and add them to the listbox)?

Comment: What you're asking for is dynamic code execution, but it isn't what you should use. What you should use is some kind of lookup table, for instance a [**`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me - although you might need to adapt it slightly to change the path of where you want to save the text file and in the sub that executes the game's exe file. I've added comments so you should be able to see what's going on.

```
Public Class Form1

    'This is where your list of games will be stored
    Dim GamesList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    'The filepath and name of your games text file
    Dim GamesListPathName = "K:\GamesList.txt"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddGamesToDictionary()
        PopulateListBox()
    End Sub

    'Checks to see if your text file containing the list of games exists.
    'If it does, read  it into the games list dictionary and
    'populates your list box
    Private Sub AddGamesToDictionary()
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(GamesListPathName) Then
            LoadGamesList()
        Else
            GamesList.Add("Defender", "C:\Program Files\Defender\Defender.exe")
            GamesList.Add("Asteroids", "C:\Program Files\Asteroids\Asteroids.exe")
            GamesList.Add("Space Invaders", "C:\Program Files\Space Invaders\invaders.exe")
        End If
        SaveGameList()
    End Sub

    'Reads the text file that contains your list of games and paths
    'onto the games list dictionary
    Private Sub LoadGamesList()
        Dim GamesListString As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(GamesListPathName)
        Dim tempGamesListArray() As String
        tempGamesListArray = Split(GamesListString, vbCrLf)

        For Each item As String In tempGamesListArray
            If Not item = "End Of List" Then
                Dim game As String
                Dim gamePathName As String
                game = Split(item, ",")(0)
                gamePathName = Split(item, ",")(1)
                GamesList.Add(game, gamePathName)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    'Saves the games in the games dictionary to the text file
    Private Sub SaveGameList()
        Dim filetext As String = ""
        For Each game As String In GamesList.Keys
            filetext = filetext & game & "," & GamesList(game) & vbCrLf
        Next
        filetext = filetext & "End Of List"
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(GamesListPathName, filetext, False)
    End Sub

    'Populates the listbox with the games in the games dictionary
    Private Sub PopulateListBox()
        lbListBox.Items.Clear()
        For Each game As String In GamesList.Keys
            lbListBox.Items.Add(game)
        Next
    End Sub

    'When the btnAddGame is clicked, if both textboxes aren't empty,
    'add the text to the games dictionary and repopulate the listbox
    Private Sub btnAddGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddGame.Click
        If txtDataAdd.Text > "" And txtFilePath.Text > "" Then
            Dim game As String = txtDataAdd.Text
            Dim pathName As String = txtFilePath.Text
            GamesList.Add(game, pathName)
            SaveGameList()
            PopulateListBox()
        End If
    End Sub

    'When the listbox is clicked, make sure an item is selected
    'and start the process using the path name associated with the item selected
    Private Sub lbListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        If lbListBox.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            Dim pathName As String = GamesList.Item(lbListBox.SelectedItem)
            Process.Start(pathName)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also cheers for the clear answer and the comments, I can see where I was going wrong and how to improve.